# DbContext with and without { get; set; } in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF code first and my experience with c# is limited.

I created an entity but I didn't put `{ get; set; }`.  EF failed to detect the key.  After adding `{ get; set; }`, it detected.

I wonder what's the difference having / not having `{ get; set; }` ?

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

and

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId
    public string CategoryName
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Essential reading: [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

Comment: Are you using EF6 or EF Core? Not that it matters, as in both cases EF does not support binding query-result columns to fields, only properties.

Comment: @Dai I think I'm using EF Core, not EF6.  Actually, I didn't know there is a EF6 and EF Core.  I'll read up on that.  Thanks.

Comment: @EBDS EF6 is older and now EOL'd, EF Core is its replacement, but the two didn't reach feature-parity until very recently - that's why a lot of people still use EF6 today. (Also, EF Core _only_ runs on .NET Core/.NET 5+, while EF6 is for .NET Framework 4.x - but also supports .NET Core 3.1+/.NET5+ to support transitioning to the future.

Comment: @madreflection oh.  I thought there is one (ie properties) and that I can have get/set or not.  Learn something new.  I'm more used to Python and I think there is no difference.  May be I'm wrong there also.  Thanks.

Comment: @Dai then I'm fine, I guess since I just started. ;-)

Comment: Python's _Object Attributes_ are roughly equivalent to C#/.NET _Object Properties_ - with some minor differences.

Comment: If you just started, you should be using EF Core. First, make sure you are. Second, retag with [tag:entity-framework-core] to match.

Comment: @EBDS Protip: in a C# `class`, the syntax `public String MyProperty { get; set; }` _is shorthand_ for a property with its own _backing field_ (e.g. `private String myPropertyField;`). This can throw beginners off who might reasonably think that somehow properties and fields are entirely unrelated.